# to create view to allow only a consultant view placements for account

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create or replace view v_placement
as 
select * from (
select c.consultant_id,
       p.placement_id,
       p.plt_short_desc,
       p.plt_required_start_date, 
       p.plt_estimated_end_date,
       p.plt_actual_start_date,
       p.plt_actual_end_date,
       p.plt_renewal_no,
       p.plt_to_permanent,
       p.max_salary,
       p.min_salary,
       p.actual_salary 
from lds_account a,
     lds_placement p,
     my_users m,
     lds_consultant c
where a.account_id=p.fk1_account_id 
and c.consultant_id=m.consultant_id 
and upper(m.user_name)=NVL(v('APP_USER')),user)
```

i created this view and am getting error message:

> ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments

a.account_id is a primary key in account table=p.fk1_account_id is a foreign key in placement table and c.consultant_id is a primary key in consultant table=m.consultant_id is a foreign key in the my_users table to store password and username.

I want when a particular consultant login can see only his placement

Comment: Whenever you get a compilation error message, it points to the line and exact position where the error was found. In most cases that is quite helpful; it yours, it probably points to the NVL with only one argument. Try to learn how to read and take advantage of error messages, it will serve you well in the future. And when you post here, always include the full error message, not just part of it - it will help us help you. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Bad parenteses on your where clause:

```
and upper(m.user_name)=NVL(v('APP_USER'),user))
```

Also, you don't need `select * from` and the final parenthesis...

```
create or replace view v_placement
as 
select c.consultant_id,
       p.placement_id,
       p.plt_short_desc,
       p.plt_required_start_date, 
       p.plt_estimated_end_date,
       p.plt_actual_start_date,
       p.plt_actual_end_date,
       p.plt_renewal_no,
       p.plt_to_permanent,
       p.max_salary,
       p.min_salary,
       p.actual_salary 
from lds_account a,
     lds_placement p,
     my_users m,
     lds_consultant c
where a.account_id=p.fk1_account_id 
and c.consultant_id=m.consultant_id 
and upper(m.user_name)=NVL(v('APP_USER'),user)
```

Comment: Good to see that others also fight useless parenthesis